# Angular2 CanActivate Guard shows page before redirecting

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In our app, we test if the user has agreed the terms of use before giving him access to the request form.

I set a CanActivate guard checking it. In case it's false, i encounter a strange behavior: **i can see the request form in a brief time (of a blink!) before being actually redirected to the terms**. How can I prevent this behavior and DIRECTLY redirect if the guard is false.

Aren't the guards supposed to accomplish their check before activating the guarded route?

Here is my routing:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RequestFormComponent} from './request-form.component';
import { TermsComponent } from './terms.component';
import { TermsGuard } from './services/terms-guard.service';

export const secretRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'form'
  },
  {
    path: 'form',
    component: RequestFormComponent,
    canActivate: [TermsGuard ]
  },
  { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent },      

  // otherwise redirect to form
  { path: '**',  redirectTo: 'form' }
];
```

As per the same question, is there any way to define a default route in this array? To avoid writing two separate lines:

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'form'
  },
  {
    path: 'form',
    component: RequestFormComponent,
    canActivate: [TermsGuard ]
  },
```

Comment: Try using `canLoad` instead of `canActivate`.

Comment: have you tried it @StefanSvrkota ?

Comment: I tried it but i don't exactly know how it works. I replaced canActivate with canLoad (with proper imports of course), but the component is activated and do not prevent the user to access the form.

Comment: 5 years later I have the same problem with setting guard for the home page... did you find a solution for that @BlackHoleGalaxy

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for an answer to this.

To cancel navigation try returning in your guard's canActivate method an url tree.

Whenever a UrlTree is returned from a route guard, Angular fires a NavigationCancel event, thus effectively cancelling all running navigation events and kicking off a new navigation to the indicated URL.

```
return this.router.createUrlTree(['/no-such-page'])
```